# Multiply various subsets of a data frame by different vectors

Tags: r, vector, subset, multiplication

I would like to multiply several columns in my data frame by a vector of values.  The specific vector of values changes depending on the value in another column.

--EDIT--

What if I make the data set more complicated, i.e., more than 2 conditions and the conditions are randomly shuffled around the data set?

Here is an example of my data set:

```
df=data.frame(
  Treatment=(rep(LETTERS[1:4],each=2)),
  Species=rep(1:4,each=2),
  Value1=c(0,0,1,3,4,2,0,0),
  Value2=c(0,0,3,4,2,1,4,5),
  Value3=c(0,2,4,5,2,1,4,5),
  Condition=c("A","B","A","C","B","A","B","C")
  )
```

Which looks like:

```
 Treatment Species Value1 Value2 Value3 Condition
     A       1      0      0      0         A
     A       1      0      0      2         B 
     B       2      1      3      4         A
     B       2      3      4      5         C
     C       3      4      2      2         B
     C       3      2      1      1         A
     D       4      0      4      4         B
     D       4      0      5      5         C
```

If `Condition=="A"`, I would like to multiply columns 3-5 by the vector `c(1,2,3)`.  If `Condition=="B"`, I would like to multiply columns 3-5 by the vector `c(4,5,6)`.  If `Condition=="C"`, I would like to multiply columns 3-5 by the vector `c(0,1,0)`.  The resulting data frame would therefore look like this:

```
 Treatment Species Value1 Value2 Value3 Condition
     A       1      0      0      0         A
     A       1      0      0     12         B 
     B       2      1      6     12         A
     B       2      0      4      0         C
     C       3     16     10     12         B
     C       3      2      2      3         A
     D       4      0     20     24         B
     D       4      0      5      0         C
```

I have tried subsetting the data frame and multiplying by the vector:

```
t(t(subset(df[,3:5],df[,6]=="A")) * c(1,2,3))
```

But I can't return the subsetted data frame to the original.  Is there any way to perform this operation without subsetting the data frame, so that other columns (e.g., Treatment, Species) are preserved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a fairly general solution that you should be able to adapt to fit your needs.

Note the first argument in the `outer` call is a logical vector and the second is numeric, so before multiplication `TRUE` and `FALSE` are converted to `1` and `0`, respectively.  We can add the `outer` results because the conditions are non-overlapping and the `FALSE` elements will be zero.

```
multiples <-
  outer(df$Condition=="A",c(1,2,3)) +
  outer(df$Condition=="B",c(4,5,6)) +
  outer(df$Condition=="C",c(0,1,0))

df[,3:5] <- df[,3:5] * multiples
```

Comment: +1 Really need to wrap my brain around these inner/outer functions. Thanks for a usage case.

Comment: Also works great, although not quite sure what it's doing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*Edited to reflect some notes from the comments*

Assuming that `Condition` is a factor, you could do this:

```
#Modified to reflect OP's edit - the same solution works just fine
m <- matrix(c(1:6,0,1,0),3,3,byrow = TRUE)
df[,3:5] <- with(df,df[,3:5] * m[Condition,])
```

which makes use of fairly quick vectorized multiplication. And obviously, wrapping this in `with` isn't strictly necessary, it's just what popped out of my brain. Also note the subsetting comment below by Backlin.

More globally, remember that every subsetting you can do with `subset` you can also do with `[`, and crucially, `[` support assignment via `[<-`. So if you want to alter a portion of a data frame or matrix, you can always use this type of idiom:

```
df[rowCondition,colCondition] <- <replacement values>
```

assuming of course that `<replacement values>` is the same dimension as your subset of `df`. It may work otherwise, but you will run afoul of R's recycling rules and R may kick back a warning.

Comment: Or how about `df[3:5] <- df[3:5] * t(matrix(1:6, 3, 2)[,df$Condition])`? Even more compact. You don't need the comma when indexing data frames if you're getting entire columns and factors are automatically interpreted as integers when used for indexing.

Comment: I totally agree with the `as.integer` being unnecessary. However, I generally prefer being explicit when subsetting about whether I intend it to apply to rows/cols, but that's a matter of style. Personally, I find it easier to read that way. But then, you can always nitpick this stuff to death. I mean, I used `with` to avoid typing `df$`! ;)

Comment: Haha, true. Sometimes I get carried away trying to compress everything as hard as possible. But `with` it is one letter longer than `df$` after all, just think of everything you could have written with that letter you wasted!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-vectorized, but easy to understand solution:

```
 replaceFunction <- function(v){
   m <- as.numeric(v[3:5])
   if (v[6]=="A")
     out <- m * c(1,2,3)
   else if (v[6]=="B")
     out <- m * c(4,5,6)
   else
     out <- m
   return(out)
 }

 g <- apply(df, 1, replaceFunction)
 df[3:5] <- t(g)
 df
```

Comment: Great answer!  That did it, and I was finally able to successfully implement if else statements.  R did kick out a warning after `df[3:5]=t(g)` when I applied it to my larger dataset, but the values appear correctly in the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

```
df[3:5] <- df[3:5] * t(sapply(df$Condition, function(x) if(x=="B") 4:6 else 1:3))
```

Or by vector multiplication

```
df[3:5] <- df[3:5] * (3*(df$Condition == "B") %*% matrix(1, 1, 3)
                      + matrix(1:3, nrow(df), 3, byrow=T))
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting approach.  How would I integrate if else statements if I had more than one condition?  (see above)

Comment: I'd go for something like what joran suggested. Making a matrix with rows corresponding to each possible case and then index them in some clever way.